# SharePoint 2013 App Update - The operation took too long

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am baffled by this one.  On my dev environment updating my custom app works fine.  On my live server I can install the app however when I publish a new version and try to update the app I get error.

The operation took too long.  Intermittent (Retry operation)

Any advice on this or how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

The Custom app uses angular, ckeditor and has a client web-part also.

Comment: Try to retract the app and then redeploy it, and then updating it

Comment: by retract you mean delete the app from the app catalog from central admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to system resources: mainly on the db, search crawl topology was separated to new servers, this has solved the install issue.